# Javavscript change sub-class property on instantiation

Tags: javascript, oop

if I have

```
myClass.prototype.subClass=
{
foo:false
}
```

when I create a new instance on an object how can I set foo to a different value each time, so how do I refer to that sub-class here

```
var newObj = new myclass();
```

Comment: To clarify: Do you want each instance to have its own `subClass.foo` value, or do you want to change it every time for *all* instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects and arrays are not something which should be added to the prototype *unless* you want to share them with all instances.

As soon as you want properties of these objects to be different for each instances, you have to assign the object in the constructor (or in any other function) to the specific instance:

```
this.subClass = {
    foo: true
    // potentially other properties
};
```

That said, there might be cases were having a "default" object in the prototype might be reasonable, but you should not write to it.

---

Assigning the object in the constructor instead does not duplicate code and allows you to change it for each instance individually.

---

**Update:**

If you don't want to change the original constructor, you can either just add a new function to the prototype and call it whenever you instantiate an object:

```
MyClass.prototype.init = function() {
    this.subClass = {
        //...
    };
};
```

and

```
var obj = new MyClass();
obj.init();
```

Or you really create a new constructor function:

```
function MySubClass() {
    MyClass.apply(this, arguments);
    // now create that object for each instance
    this.subClass = {
        foo: someValue
    };
}

inherits(MySubClass, MyClass);
```

where `inherits` is defined as:

```
function inherits(Child, Parent) {
    var Tmp_ = function() {};
    Tmp_.prototype = Parent.prototype;
    Child.prototype = new Tmp_();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}
```

Then you will use `MySubClass` instead of `MyClass` to create the instances.

Comment: I know I can access the subclass in the constructor but in this case I am adding a specific subclass to a more general constructor and don't want to alter the constructor to accommodate this task. Maybe I can use inheritance instead but I'm not too sure how to do that.

Comment: Thanks Felix not sure that is succinct enough, I'm going to try and bypass the contractor, set the sub class property then trigger the constructor after that, that is a change to the super class but one I can deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missunderstand how prototype inheritence works because this question is a bit odd. But you should be able to access the `foo` property like any other:

```
newObj.subClass.foo = newValue
```

Comment: This will change `subClass.foo` for all instances though.

Comment: Since the OP said `how can I set foo to a different value each time`, that doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: OP should probably attempt to understand prototype inheritance further.

Comment: You're right I'm going to open a different question on inheritance.